# Callouts on text positions

Tags: beamer, stacking-symbols, callout

I am trying to make a callout (for a beamer presentation) like the following

[image]

(The image is from bearing numbering, although its probably irrelevant).

I was wondering if there is a package that could do it, or if there is a smart way (I've used in the past `\stackrel` and `overset` and `underset` however they wouldn't produce an acceptable result in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TikZ:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
(Ex. 2)
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
    column sep=10pt] (m)
    {72&10&C&DT&P 5\\};
\node[align=left,
    below right=5pt of m-1-5.south east] (node5) {Tolerance class code\\ (class 5)};
\node[align=left,
    below right=35pt and 0pt of m-1-4.south east] (node4) {Matched pair or stack code\\(tandem arrangement)};
\node[align=left,
    below right=65pt and 0pt of m-1-3.south east] (node3) {Contact angle code\\(nominal contact angle, 15°)};
\node[align=left,
    below right=95pt and 0pt of m-1-2.south east] (node2) {Bore diameter number\\(nominal bore diameter, 50 mm)};
\node[align=left,
    below right=125pt and 0pt of m-1-1.south east] (node1) {Bearing series code\\$\left[\text{\makecell[l]{single-row angular contact\\ ball bearing of dimension series 02}}\right]$};
\foreach \ind in {1,2,...,5}{
\draw (m-1-\ind.south west) -- (m-1-\ind.south east);
\draw (m-1-\ind) |- (node\ind);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]